# included a new if condition in nodeJS function - not working in a previously working function

Tags: node.js, json, if-statement, google-cloud-functions

i have a working google cloud function which received data in JSON via webhook and then sends it to a 3rd party platform. It was working fine. But i needed some modification, so i included an if statement. It's not working since then giving a syntax error. Request some help:

```
exports.receiveWebhookData = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('data received', event);

  const key1 = await getSecret(key1);
  const key2 = await getSecret(key2);
  const key3 = await getSecret(key3);

  if (!key1 || !key2 || !key3) {
    return `keys are not present (expecting ${key1.name}, ${key2.name}, ${key3.name})`
  }

  let body = null;
  if (event.data.length > 0) {
    try {
      body = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString())
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Failed to parse JSON body: ", e);
      body = null;
    }
  }

  const {
    data1,
    data2,
    data3,
    data4,
    data5,
    data6,
    data7,
    data8,
    data9
  } = body || event.attributes;

  let response = {}

  if (data4 !== “load” and data6 !== “unload”){ /////this is the if statement i added ///////////      

    try {
      const ra = new roamapp({
        key1: key1
      })

      await ra.setToken(key2)

      response = await ra.sendData(data9, {
        data1: data1,
        data2: data2,
        data3: data3,
        data4: data4,
        data5: parseFloat(data5),
        data6: parseFloat(data6),
        data7: data7,
        data8: data8
      })

      console.log('data Sent', response)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error sending data', e)
      response = e
    }
  } else{
    console.log('data not sent - load unload')
  }
  return response
};
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at Module._compile

Answer (score 2):

I guess the quotes in your if condition are wrong. it should be like this

```
  if (data4 !== "load" && data6 !== "unload"){ /////this is the if statement i added ///////////
```

Also, `and` should be `&&`

Probably a copy paste issue.

Comment: are you saying it is copy paster issue in question or in the code?

Comment: Also, `and` should be `&&`

Comment: yes.. i thought it was a copy/paste issue in question.. but seems to be in function.. you were right.. and also && is correct.. fixed it.. thanks

Comment: also.. one of the data that is being received is a number.. and based on value of number.. we need to check it against our dictionary key.. and use it's value to reassign the variable..

for eg. data4 is received as 10.. we have a dictionary - const ourdict = {10:"new", 11:"old", 12:"new", 13:"old"}

so if data4 is 10, then we need to reassign data4 to value of ourdict[10].value... 

how to go about this.. pl note i am versed with python not node.. hence these issues